# Grails spring-security-core plugin tutorial

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using Grails 2.4.5 and I have created a new application TestSecurity, created a simple controller SercuredController, that is accessible from the interface.

```
package testsecurity

class SecuredController {

    def index() { 
        render 'HELLO FROM CONTROLLER'
    }
}
```

Then I added a spring_security_core plugin: I added compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4".
Then s2-quickstart com.testapp User Role

Then I start the application and spring_security doesn't allow me to enter http://localhost:8080/TestSecurity/secured/index and ask for the password and login.
I haven't added @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN']) or any other annotations. 
How to fix this bug?

In tutorial http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#tutorials it is said that without annotation the controller must not be secured and can be accessed.

Config.groovy file looks as follows:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.testapp.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.testapp.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.testapp.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']
]
```

Comment: Tutorial URL is now 404, top level URL that still works - http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/

Answer (score 2):

I have used @Secured(['ROLE_ANONYMOUS']) annotation on my controller. And security has started to work.

Comment: I'll be updating the tutorial this week to include a note that in 2.0 by default every URL needs an access rule (even if anyone can access it)

Answer (score 1):

You should use annotations. To secure you controllers. 
Or change grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigTyp if you don't like annotations.

Read this:

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html#securedAnnotations

By default all urls are secured. To change this try:

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false

Read the documentation for this options:

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html

**ATTENTION:**

As Burt Beckwith commented below, it is not a good idea to disable rejectIfNoRule  and rejectPublicInvocations. So it is not a recommendation to use this, but it can be helpful if you just want to test something!

Comment: Thank you very much, CyberAleks!

Comment: Please don't recommend that people disable a sensible feature like rejectIfNoRule when it's trivial to add some annotations or database requestmaps or add to the config maps in Config.groovy

Comment: That wasn't a recommendation. As I said 'You should use annotations' and he asked 'without annotation the controller must not be secured and can be accessed'. That was just an answer of his question.

Comment: Both URLs are 404 top level URL that still works http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/